# code in c on local machine is fine but runtime error on hackerrank in algorithm warm up exercise "angry children"?

Tags: c

i uploaded a code in c for problem "angry children" in algorithm section of hackerrank. for testcase #2 it is showing runtime error while on my local machine(ubuntu 14.04, x86) in gcc it is giving answer 1335 which is correct ans according to the testcase #2 output given by them. please tell me what to do to make hackerrank accept my code perfectly it is working for all other testcaases.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
long long int *insertion(long long int ar[],long long int n)
{
    long long int i,j,v;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        v=ar[i];j=i;
        while(ar[j-1]>v){
            ar[j]=ar[j-1];j--;
            }
            ar[j]=v;
            }return ar;
}
int main()
{
long long int i,a,b,c,temp;
long long int n,k;
scanf("%lld",&n);
long long int ar[n+1];
assert(1<=n<=100000);
scanf("%lld",&k);
assert(1<=k<=n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    scanf("%lld",&ar[i]);
    assert(0<= ar[i] <=1000000000);
    }
insertion(ar,n);
//for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
//{
//  printf("%lld\n",ar[i]);}
long long int f,min=9999999999;
for(i=1;i<=n-k+1;i++)
{
f=ar[i+k-1]-ar[i];
if(f<min)
    min=f;
}
printf("%lld\n",min);
return 0;   
}
```

this is my code in c please tell me why it is shoeing segmentation fault on hackerrank compiler?

Comment: `v=ar[i];j=i;
        while(ar[j-1]>v){
            ar[j]=ar[j-1];j--;
            }` WHY dont you use a for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in your insertion sort function, which doesn't check to see if `j` becomes less than 1. As a result, your code is liable to go marching off into the wilderness whenever it tries to insert a value at the start of the list.

The fix is simple. Just change

```
        while(ar[j-1]>v){
```

to

```
        while(j>1 && ar[j-1]>v){
```

Or alternatively, instead of re-inventing the wheel, use one of the library functions provided in `stdlib`, like `qsort()`, for example. Much more efficient, and much less prone to errors. You'll have to adjust your code to use zero-based indexing, but [you should be doing that anyway, really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering#Advantages).